# Summing duplicates rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a database with more than 300 duplicates that look like this:

```
rate    shipment_id original_cost
8.14    500410339210    5.93
7.81    500410339221    5.93
8.53    500410339232    7.07
8.53    500410339243    14.31
2.76    500410345319    68.87
... ... ... ...
8.46    987506030619    7.36
8.46    987506030620    7.36
7.32    987506030630    6.80
27.82   997311250164181 144.44
7.32    997355250064942 19.83
```

I want that for each duplicate shipment_id only original_cost gets added together and rates remain as they are.

```
rate    shipment_id original_cost
3.06    926401748430    2.54
3.06    926401748430    19.60
16.34   926401748430    2.54
16.34   926401748430    19.60
```

like for these duplicates:
it should look something like this:

```
rate    shipment_id original_cost
3.06    926401748430    22.14
3.06    926401748430    22.14
16.34   926401748430    22.14
16.34   926401748430    22.14
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the duplicate values (`['shipment_id', 'rate']`) and use `transform` on the "original_cost" column to calculate the sum:

```
df['original_cost'] = df.groupby(['shipment_id', 'rate'])['original_cost'].transform('sum')
```

Example input:

```
    rate    shipment_id original_cost
0   3.06    926401748430    22.14
1   3.06    926401748430    22.14
2   16.34   926401748430    22.14
3   16.34   926401748430    22.14
```

Example output:

```
    rate   shipment_id  original_cost
0   3.06  926401748430          22.14
1   3.06  926401748430          22.14
2  16.34  926401748430          22.14
3  16.34  926401748430          22.14
```

Comment: can you please provide me an output, according to this question, now?

Comment: I added an example. I had to make a mix of both your examples as in the first one there are only unique ids and in the second only one duplicate. Does it work for you?

Comment: can you refresh the question, you might see what exactly needs to be done, the second example is a part of the first example.

Comment: OK, then also group by `rate`, see update

Comment: can you help me with my new question?